Does inversion occur in ipso substitution of vinyl silanes?
The electrophilic attack on vinyl silane is highly regioselective and stereoselective and the substitution occurs at ipso position. However, I believe some amount of inversion of configuration can also take place.
So I want to find any source for the same? And if it is too rare to happen, I want a reasoning for the same?
Following is from Wikipedia

Vinylsilane additions proceed with retention of double bond configuration, and follow a similar principle. After addition of the electrophile to the top or bottom face of the double bond, the silyl moiety rotates to become parallel to the adjacent empty 2p orbital. The principle of least motion provides that the electrophile moves into a position close to that formerly occupied by the silyl group. Thus, the configuration of the double bond is retained after loss of the silyl group.



Related.

@user55119 so that still means some possibility of the product to be rotated during the carbocation formation right? I mean rotations happen $10^{13}$ per second and thus steric factors should not make it stereospecific?

Is the reaction stereospecific? Yes. It is also highly stereoselective.

@user55119 does it mean accepting the fact in reality no inversion occurs due to experiments prolly conducted in this case?
